# Error : Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

Tags: .net, frameworks

One of the users of my application got the error "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application". My application is set to have .NET framework targeted at v3.5. I've asked him to install .NET framework 3.5 but he's still getting the error.

I've tried solutions from several websites, added a config file with the code as follows:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0"/>
  <supportedRuntime version ="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

However the problem didn't seem to go away. The same thing happened on both his computers (Windows XP and Vista). What are other possible causes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your config say if you have version 4.0 then use it else fallback to the next i.e. v2

But as per MSDN the attribute useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy is to be used for fallback

> **Taken from MSDN**
>
> Specifies whether to enable the .NET Framework version 2.0 runtime
>   activation policy or to use the .NET Framework version 4 activation
>   policy.

So i would suggest you use it this way

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version = "v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

with a similar problem, not being able to run RETSCREEN.EXE due to following error:

> Error parsing c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2..50727\config\machine.config 
>   Parser returned error 0xC00CE556

I followed the solution published in:
http://blogs.sits-solutions.com/2010/11/02/parser-returned-error-0xc00ce556/

> It turns out that “machine.config” file (as the error suggests) is the
>   problem. The “machine.config” can be found on the CONFIG folder
>   located under
>   “%SystemRoot%\microsoft.NEt\framework\v2.0.50727\config”. So:
>
> ```
> Logon as admin
> Go to “c:\windows\microsoft.NEt\framework\v2.0.50727\config” and rename “machine.config” to something like “machine.config.BAD”
> In the same location create a folder called TEMP
> Copy “machine.config.default” from the CONFIG folder to TEMP folder
> Go into TEMP folder and rename “machine.config.default” to “machine.config”
> Copy “machine.config” from TEMP folder back to CONFIG folder
> Restart your machine
> ```
>
> Your C00CE556 error should be solved.

actually I did not need to copy in another folder: made a copy of machine.config.default in the same folder and renamed it.